# Implementation of min Heap with two parameters for sorting [Java]

Tags: java, sorting, priority-queue

I am trying to implement a min heap in java which sorts based on two parameters. Each element of the min heap is an object which contains an int and a string. My current implementation sorts solely based on the integer but I also need it to sort in alphabetical order. For example, if the contents of the objects are as follows:

{ (stopped, 3), (anywhere, 1), (food, 17), (get, 3), (done, 1)}

the output when removing elements from the heap must be:

{(anywhere, 1), (done, 1), (get, 3), (stopped, 3), (food, 17)}

My sink and swim functions are described below:

```
 private void swim(int n){
        while (n > 1 && greater(n/2, n)){
            exchange(n, n/2);
            n = n/2;
        }
    }
 private boolean greater(int i, int j){
        return elements[i].getValue() >= elements[j].getValue();
    }
    private void exchange(int i, int j){
        Node tmp = elements[i];
        elements[i] = elements[j];
        elements[j] = tmp;
    }
    private void sink(int k){
        while(2*k <=n){
            int i = 2*k;
            if(i < n && greater(i, i+1)) i++;
            if(!greater(k,i)) break;
            exchange(k,i);
            k = i;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

## Update

Thank you very much to @AlbertoSinigaglia, your solution worked!

Comment: So to clarify, you would like to sort first alphabetically, and the sort those ties by number? It would help if you included some String ties (duplicates) in your example

Comment: what on earth is this sorting? {(anywhere, 1), (done, 1), (get, 3), (stopped, 1), (food, 17)}? it's neither alphabetical neither numerical

Comment: @sleepToken Correct.  I would like to first sort alphabetically and then numerically. Thus, the first letter of anywhere comes before the first letter of done and thus anywhere goes first. This continues throughout the list until a larger number is found.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia
Apologies, for the error. It should read:{(anywhere, 1), (done, 1), (get, 3), (stopped, 3), (food, 17)} . I'll make an edit

Comment: well in greater use elements[i].getValue()>elements[j].getValue || (elements[i].getValue()==elements[j].getValue() && elements[i].getString().compareTo(elements[j].getString())>0)

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Thank you so much! It worked!!

Comment: @BJW97 i've created a answer in order to close this question and to be more clear, with a proper explanation, for future visitors and for you if you need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to update the `greater` method in this way:

```
return /*1*/ elements[i].getValue()>elements[j].getValue 
           || 
         /*2*/ (elements[i].getValue()==elements[j].getValue() && elements[i].getString().compareTo(elements[j].getString())>0)
```

With 1 you check if the int Value is greater, if yes, well ends there, if else it's not, it should be o `=` or `<` and we need to take care of the `=` case, so if the Values are equals, then we compare the String with the `compareTo()` method, which will return `>0` in case the first String is greater than the second string